# SOAP webservice used to work in XAMARIN.FORMS, but now it doesn't work on any device below Android 6.0

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Suddenly i got reports form user that a list in my app didn't show any data - It worked fine on my device. Later i found out that everything works fine and dandy on all android devices with 6.0 installed - every android version below 6.0(Marshmallow), wont get data transferred! I am at a loss - have no idea what has happened or how to fix this.... Help!

Does anyone recognize this or have possible solution to how this can be fixed?

In my forms app i have a portable library where i have a class handling the SOAP webservice, it is implemented like below:

```
public class soapwebservice
{
//private Uri baseUri = new Uri("uri");
private static DataConnection _instance = null;
private HttpClient client = null;

//Contructor
private DataConnection()
{
    client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
    client.BaseAddress = baseUri;
}
public static DataConnection Instance { get { if (_instance == null) _instance = new DataConnection(); return _instance; } }

public async Task<Other.ServiceResponse> RefreshRouteList()
{
    try
    {
        var soapString = this.constructRefreshsoap();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "https://trolderuterne.play2know.dk/GetRoutes");
        var content = new StringContent(soapString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

        using (var response = await client.PostAsync("/Classes/mobileServices.asmx", content))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Other.ServiceResponse>(ParseSoapResponse(soapResponse));
            }
            return new ServiceResponse { Code = Codes.ServerError, Message = response.StatusCode.ToString() };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ServiceResponse
        {
            Code = Codes.ServerError,
            Message = ex.Message
        };
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

The error message i get when running the app is: 
"Error: NameResolutionFailure"

I have now tried to consume the webservice directly in the android project instead of the PCL.

Just to mention it i have my webservice going over a proxy, due to security. It still works on 6.0, but when i go to a simulator running 4.4 i still get error: "Error: NameResolutionFailure".

I tried grabbing the original webservice directly from our server and I get the following error message: "Error: ConnectFailure (Network is unreachable)"

Hopefully someone has some insight, and can tell me how to get the data i need from the webservice in devices below Android 6.0!

Comment: When you say your using a proxy, do you mean `java.net.Proxy` or ....?

Comment: I mean a proxy webservice. Never the less i have tried a random webservice from the internet:

http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx

And i get the exact same error when running it in a completely new project! The more i try the more im convinced it is a error/bug in Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asked by XAMARIN suppport to install the beta version og their software and this "kinda" solved the issue. I can now consume a SOAP webservice, but the service cant be SSL encrypted, if you want to use android below 6.0.

So i removed the SSL encryption from our proxy and now it works with all versions!

Answer (score 0):

NameResolutionFailure looks like a DNS error. But you're going through a proxy, so who knows what they are doing. Did they change something recently? Can you try to resolve the name into an IP both with and without the proxy, over WiFi and mobile data too?

ConnectFailure looks like you cannot connect to the server. Can you try to get data directly from the IP address instead? Try both directly and through the proxy, over WiFi and mobile data too.

Android 6 changed some things related to SSL, could that be affecting it?

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks for responding.

Indeed it could seem like it could be via the proxy - But i have tried a random weather service from the internet and tried to consume that to check if it would throw the same error.

I used: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx

and as predicted it throws the same error!


Actually i just saw the changes to the SSL and i thought that it could be the problem, but on the random weather webservice i dont see any SSL encryption..

Comment: Ohh - And the funny thing is everything works on Android 6.0, all kinds of of exceptions below that!

Comment: Thanks for staying with this @Joe! im quite sure i tested both on mobile data and wifi -but to be sure im testing it now! I'll be testing both the proxy and with a direct IP over wifi and mobiledata - Who knows, it might yield some results! Ill get back to you shortly!